# Rsync Daemon Max Connections Traffic Jam

Tags: rsync

I prefer to use rsync daemon for all of my rync needs because it provides clean centralized management and saves on system resources.  Accordingly, my `/etc/rsyncd.conf` contains multiple module entries.

My wrapper scripts for my actual rsync commands are all `while` loops that will instantly / repeatedly re-connect rsync in case of dropped connections.

**Problem:**
The `max connections = 1` variable entry for each module is being read *globally* rather than *individually* per each module.  Thereby causing  `@ERROR: max connections (1) reached -- try again later` to take place (whichever rsync-daemon connects first gets the single available *incorrectly global* `max connection = 1`, causing all other connections to fail.. annoying ).

Without the `max connections = 1`, the `while` loop has the ability to spin up unlimited threads and consume unnecessary resources, hence a connections per module limit. Meanwhile the `max connections = 1` has the accompanying `per module` file.lock per documentation.

This is my `/etc/rsyncd.conf`:

```
[home]
path = /home/username
list = yes
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
uid = root
gid = root
read only = yes
# Data source information
max connections = 1
lock file = /var/run/rsyncd-home.lock

[prod-bkup]
path = /media/username/external/Server-Backups/Prod/today
list = yes
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
uid = root
gid = root
# Don't allow to modify the source files
read only = yes
max connections = 1
lock file = /var/run/rsyncd-prod-bkup.lock

[test-bkup]
path = /media/username/external/Server-Backups/Test/today
list = yes
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
uid = root
gid = root
# Don't allow to modify the source files
read only = yes
max connections = 1
lock file = /var/run/rsyncd-test-bkup.lock

[VminRoot2]
path = /root/VDI-Files
list = yes
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
uid = root
gid = root
# Don't allow to modify the source files
read only = yes
max connections = 1
lock file = /var/run/rsyncd-VminRoot2.lock
```

This is an example of one of my rsync-daemon wrapper scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
while [ 1 ]
do

   cputool --load-limit 7.5 -- nice -n -15 rsync -avxP --no-i-r --rsync-path="rsync" --log-file=/var/log/rsync-home.log --exclude 'snap'  --exclude 'lost+found' --exclude=".*" --exclude=".*/" 127.0.0.1::home /media/username/external/home-files-only && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
   
    if [ "$?" = "0" ] ; then
        echo "rsync completed normally"
        exit
    else
        echo "Rsync failure. Backing off and retrying..."
        sleep 10
    fi
done

#end of shell script
```

**Question**
How can I get rid of the `ERROR: max connections (1) reached -- try again later` error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I finally arrived at was to ensure that my `while loop` only executes once, if the connection has not been established yet and/or connection broken.

**Note:** My solutions, rather workarounds, should not be necessary given the correct according to documentation rsync-daemon configs, but it seems that despite having individually named `.lock` files for each modules, the first script with a `while loop` was somehow still somehow able to connect(rather block) the other `.lock` files from being used by the other respective scripts.  (rsync bug?)

**Solution 1 (quick & dirty):**

`flock -n <lock file> <script>`

Or in my case, using this command to execute my cron job:

`flock -n /var/run/rsyncd-home.lock /path/to/my_script.sh`

*caveat* - this leaves your script vulnerable to stale lock files that may prevent execution on the next time interval.

**Solution 2:**
So, I used a *bullet-proof* method (so I think... I invite folks to correct my understanding, if need be)...

First, I did `apt install procmail`

From there I edited `/usr/local/bin/backupscript.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
LOCK=/var/run/rsyncd-home.lock
remove_lock()
{
    rm -f "$LOCK"
}
another_instance()
{
    echo "There is another instance running, exiting"
    exit 1
}
lockfile -r 0 -l 3600 "$LOCK" || another_instance
trap remove_lock EXIT

#new using rsyncd & perpetual restart
while [ 1 ]
do
   cputool --load-limit 7.5 -- nice -n -15 rsync -avxP --no-i-r --rsync-path="rsync" --log-file=/var/log/rsync-home.log --exclude 'lost+found' --exclude=".*" --exclude=".*/" 127.0.0.1::home /media/username/external/home-files-only && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
   
    if [ "$?" = "0" ] ; then
        echo "rsync completed normally"
        exit
    else
        echo "Rsync failure. Backing off and retrying..."
        sleep 10
    fi
done

#end of shell script
```

**PRESTO:**
The script will only connect to rsync daemon once, it will re-connect on dropped connections thanks to the while loop, and there is no danger of stale lock files interrupting my backup process at future intervals... (i.e. problem solved).